# javascript - variable values from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my site, I have a js file that performs some calculations. Currently I have my variables defined in another js file as global variables.

I would like to make them dynamical. By this I mean I want them to pull values from mysql database. I know that this is possible with ajax:

EXAMPLE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'call.php',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    var tag_name = data[0];
    var client_id = data[1];
});
```

However, this is suitable for few values ( lets say 2 to 10). In my case there are many variables (circa 200). I think that it is not so good idea to make array of size 200 or more.

If I am wrong correct me please. Or if there is better solution to this, please inspire me :).

Thank you

Comment: well you can make a json array in php and use in JS.

Comment: We have processors with 6 cores, ticking at 4 GHZ. We have access to memory ranging from 8gigs (which is low standard today) and our internet connections are 10 mbits upwards. What makes you think that 2 or 10 variables are acceptable and 200 isn't, when it's just a tiny, bitsy fraction of what a regular smartphone can chew?

Comment: 200 variables isn't a lot, but it looks like OP is looking for a more efficient way of parsing them out. In which case use dot notation and feed the data from your php as an appropriately defined Json object. Then you can refer to the values as data.tag_name in you frontend code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have over 200 variables like you wrote here, I think you are organizing the code wrong.  You should organize the code into objects that represent an object mapping of your database and call php functions according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In call.php use

```
print json_encode($data_array);
exit();
```

to encode your array. 
You already have dataType: 'json' in your javascript $.ajax function. You will NOT need to write var client_id = data[1]; Your data will be accesible through data.user_id, data.tag_name.